# How to populate the quickfix list or location list of Vim/Neovim with arbitrary linter output?

Tags: vim, neovim

Say I just ran a linter in the terminal and I have a bunch of linter output in the standard format:

```
path/to/some/file.foo:45:23: This is an error message
path/to/some/file.foo:46:12: This is another error message
...
```

I am currently opening each file manually in Neovim, navigating to the correct line and fixing the issue.

Instead, I want to populate the quickfix or location list in Vim or Neovim with this information so I can quickly jump to each spot and fix the error.

**What would be the simplest/quickest way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the `:help -q` command-line flag is for:

```
$ vim -q errorfile
```

You can redirect the output of your linter to a file and then pass that file to Vim's `-q`:

```
$ yourlinter file.foo > errorfile
$ vim -q errorfile
```

If your shell allows it, you can use process substitution to remove intermediary steps and ghost files:

```
$ vim -q <(yourlinter)
```

Or, if you already ran your linter and forgot to pass it to Vim, you can re-run it and pass it to Vim via process substitution:

```
$ vim -q <(!!)
```

Since this is a situation I often find myself in, I added this command to my `bash` config years ago:

```
# open Vim with output of last command in quickfix
vimq() {
    vim -q <($(fc -nl -1))
}
```

which allows me to do:

```
$ yourlinter file.foo
(output of linter)
$ vimq
```

NOTE: `fc -nl -1` is a more portable—therefore preferable in a scripting context—way to recall the last command than `!!`. See `$ man fc`.

NOTE: you only mentioned the quickfix *list* in your question but, if you also want the quickfix *window*, you can add one more item to the command: `:help :cwindow`.

```
$ vim -q <(!!) +cw
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!